# Twig change meta data

Tags: twig

i need to get meta data of the page in twig, for replace them by my values, but i don't find how get them.

For now i have :

```
{% if spec.name matches '{meta}'  %}
       {% set getdatas = app.request.server.get('REQUEST_URI') %} // use uri for test, i need the same but with meta_title, meta_description...
       {{ dump(uri|replace({'domaine': spec.name})) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you using inheritance in the template? Is this specific template extending another? Post the code for the parent template

Comment: Yes my templace is include by this parent template :

edit : i post it in a comment in code

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override anything in Twig, you need to create a block for it. As an example:

base.html.twig

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  {% block meta %}{% endblock %}
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

parent.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  # My extra styles...
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

child.html.twig

```
{% extends 'parent.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}My page{% endblock %}

{% block meta %}
  <meta key="value">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}My content{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks that help me !
I have my parent who extends my base.html, but my page where i get my values doesnt extends the parent.
My parent get a block of my child, i'ts possible to get value from this ?
Like this (in parent.html) :
{% block content %}
{% block meta data %} myvalue {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

In my child :
{% block metadata %} <meta description="test"> {% endblock %}

Answer (score 0):

my parent template :

```
{% extends 'DesignBundle::Front/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}



<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/extension/css/flag-icon.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/extension/css/main.css') }}">
{% endblock %}


{% block title %}
{{ _("Caractéristiques des noms de domaine") ~ " ." ~ extension.nomExt|idna_decode }}</code>



{% if extension.countryName is not empty %}
   {{ " - " ~ extension.countryName|utf8_fix }}
   {% endif %}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %} // view in first post is call here
{% include 'ExtensionBundle:New_fiche:show_content.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```